# ModelState.IsValid is true if password is empty string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, modelstate

I am passing login model to mvc4 default login method

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && _webSecurity.login(model))
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

My Model looks like following

```
var _loginModel = new LoginModel
        {
            UserName = abc@gmail.com,
            Password = ""
        };
```

but ModelState.IsValid is returning true . I don't know why . Help me

Thanks in advance .

**Edit**

Here is my `LoginModel`

```
 public class LoginModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you post `LoginModel` class defination?

Comment: try this  [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]

Comment: @Amit no still same result .

Comment: try `TryValidateModel(model)` once, Please post view code also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation Attribute defined in the model will be apllied while Model Binding, u don't have to do this manualy.

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.",MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

For more complex validation you also could add a regex filter like this:

```
    [RegularExpression(@"^[^\<\>]*$", ErrorMessage = "May not contain <,>")]
```

This would match windows group policy password filter for example:

```
    (?=^.{6,255}$)((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]))^.*
```

Comment: will get complicated as soon as you want to apply difficult custom logic to model fields (disallow certain special chars or force usage of numbers, specialchars and different casing), but for this case it should be working